# Почтовые домены mail.ru - перестали доходить письма

Tags: сервер, администрирование, dns, email

Возникла проблема с тем, что в один момент перестали доходить письма на все домены mail.ru. Не могу сказать когда именно это произошло, но в конце ноября точно все работало корректно. Ну учитывая репутацию mail.ru как почты с самыми жесткими смап фильтрами, есть подозрение что у них возникли какие-то новые требования к серверу отправителя. Есть ли у кого нибудь информация, что на этот раз?

---

Все почтовые серверы google, yandex, yahoo письма с моего сервера получаю с пометкой всех пройденных проверок.
Имеется:

- SPF
- DMARK
- PTR
- ADSP

Ну в общем все настроено, все работает, всем письма доходят, кроме конечно же mail.ru

Comment: а что в логах почтового сервера?

Comment: В логах вот что валяется  status=deferred (host mxs.mail.ru[94.100.180.104] said: 421 Please try again later

Comment: С MX-записью всё нормально? MAIL.RU славится особой придирчивостью к корректности данного параметра в DNS

Comment: Не очень ясно что с ней может быть не так - domain.ru. MX 10 domain.ru . При этом, как я упомянул выше, письма нормально два месяца назад корректно доходили. С тех пор ни одна DNS запись не была изменена.

Comment: спросите у мейла. Может, какой-нибудь DKIM хотят. А может, получили от вас много писем, посчитали спамом, и ЧС добавили. Или грейлистят

Comment: DKIM есть, без него сейчас не одна серьезная почта вроде gmail письма принимать не будет.